# How to return an xml response from a java method

Tags: java, xml, dom, jax-ws

I am new to web services. So having some confusion. Is it possible to return an xml response from a method??
I have created an xml document using DOM. So trying to return the content of the the document not "the xml document" from the method.

Any hint will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This maybe able to help answer your question. [how-to-return-xml-from-web-service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925546/how-to-return-xml-from-web-service)

Comment: Thanks for your reply,